# How to transform data frame in pandas with a category column and a value column

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the following Data Frame:

| ID | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | typeA | str1 |
| ID1 | typeB | str2 |
| ID1 | typeB | str3 |
| ID2 | typeA | string1 |
| ID2 | typeB | string2 |
| ID3 | typeA | str1 |

And I would like to transform it to:

| ID | typeA | typeB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | str1 | [str2, str3] |
| ID2 | string1 | [string2] |
| ID3 | str1 |  |

I've tried using `pivot` function, but I got the following error:

`df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Category', values='Value'`

```
Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with convert values to lists:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Category', values='Value', aggfunc=list)
print (df)
Category      typeA         typeB
ID                               
ID1          [str1]  [str2, str3]
ID2       [string1]     [string2]
ID3          [str1]           NaN
```

Or if need one element lists to scalars use custom function:

```
f = lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x
df = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Category', values='Value', aggfunc=f)
print (df)
Category    typeA         typeB
ID                             
ID1          str1  [str2, str3]
ID2       string1       string2
ID3          str1           NaN
```